# GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() is null

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2014, sqlfilestream

I'm having issues getting a file from a `FILESTREAM varbinary(max)` column.

I added it to a table using this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].News ADD RowGuidColId 
     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT (NewId())
GO

ALTER TABLE News ADD NewsPngFile varbinary(max) FILESTREAM NULL
GO
```

I insert the picture using entity framework. But when I try to query, the `GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()` returns `NULL`. What might be wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you already committed the transaction?  To use this you need to explicity open a transaction, obtain the transaction context with the call to `GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()` and then commit. `GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()` will return NULL if the transaction has not been started, or has been canceled or committed.

There's a bit of documentation with an example available here:

[GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934014.aspx)